# Is there a way to wrap a callback function with useCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
items.map((item, index) => (
  <ItemReturnFeedback
    anchorText={additionalFeedbackText}
    updateParentState={(feedback) =>
      updateFeedbacks(index, feedback)
    }
    defaultText={feedbacks[index]}
  />
)
```

I want to wrap the callback function for prop `updateParentState` with useCallback so that the component can be memoized. Is there any way of doing that ?

Comment: Not an easy one. Does `<ItemReturnFeedback>` really memoise things depending on its `updateParentState` prop value?

Comment: In order to memoize the `<ItemReturnFeedback>`, the functional prop needs to be wrapped in a useCallback

Comment: Well you can memoise the whole `items.map(…)` call, if that's what you mean?